# Correct way to pass in two/multiple variables with POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-post

What's up all.

I have a form with the new `asp-...` syntax:

```
<form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Edit" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
        ...
   </div>
</form>
```

which posts back a custom class:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(CustomClass object)
{
   ...
}
```

However, I want to have it post back two different objects. Is there a new/correct way to do this with Core and the `asp-...` syntax?

If not, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: As far as I know you can only have one object. Seems to me like you are directly using your models inside your views, which you shouldn't. You should create a ViewModel for a certain action and pass all what you need in this viewmodel, the process it in the action

Comment: @Tseng I do have a ViewModel with two constructors (with parameters) which contains "CustomClass object1" and "OtherClass object2". However, when I try to pass back the ViewModel, I get hit with a "no parameterless instance" error. So I create another constructor in the VM which is parameterless, but object1 and object2 come back as null. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work for you.

Your ViewModel and it's containing classes:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public Object1 Test1 { get; set; }
    public Object2 Test2 { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {

    }

    public TestViewModel(Object1 one, Object2 two)
    {
        Test1 = one;
        Test2 = two;
    }
}

public class Object1
{
    public string TestString1 { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public string TestString2 { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```html
@model TestViewModel

<form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Test" method="post" role="form">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Test1.TestString1"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Test1.TestString1" />

    <label asp-for="@Model.Test2.TestString2"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Test2.TestString2" />

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

and finally the controller actions:

```
  public IActionResult Test()
    {
        Object1 obj1 = new Object1() { TestString1 = "test1" };
        Object2 obj2 = new Object2() { TestString2 = "test2" };
        TestViewModel vm = new TestViewModel(obj1, obj2);

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(TestViewModel vm)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug(vm.Test1.TestString1);
        _logger.LogDebug(vm.Test2.TestString2);

        return View(vm);
    }
```